# Static binary for Firefox (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, static, binary, linker

Im planning to build a simplified unix environment for Firefox (from ubuntu 20.04 elf-files). I already have X window emulation working and the next step would be porting firefox binary into this simplified unix environment.

So my question is: Is it possible to build a static binary from the ubuntu 20.04 firefox elf-files at /usr/lib/firefox/, that would include all the shared object files and would not need for example ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 for linking at runtime. The binary would have a fixed memory location and all the relocations and dependencies would be calculated beforehand? So I would just load a single binary into predefined memory location without any address relocations and jump into program entry point?